# the functionality of the word "new " in java

Tags: java

```
class Pti {

  int test = 80808080;

  Pti() { 
    System.out.println("dude ");
  }

  Pti(int test) {
    this.test=test;
  }

  public int getTest() {
    return test;
  }
}

class Epreuve {

  public static void main(String []args) {
    new Pti();  
  }

}
```

What I don't really understand is the `new Pti()`.
I know that we used `new` that to create an object like `Pti objectname = new Pti();` and that when we use `new className();` is to call a constructor 
but why do we even use that ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. We use the 'new' keyword because that is what the language defines as the operator to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good resource for understanding the differences between objects an classes in Java could be [Object-Oriented Programming Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html):

> *An **object** is a software bundle of related state and behavior.*
>
> *A **class** is a blueprint or prototype from which objects are created.*

In the provided example the `Pti` class is defined and it provides two constructors.

The `new Pti()` statement is completely valid in this context. It is instantiating an object but not assigning it to any variable.

However, this may not be particularly useful in it's current form because after the object is initialized there are no actions performed on it and the program ends right after that.

Comment: got it, thank you!